# Python Mock an object's (rasterio.DatasetWriter) writing behaviour

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, rasterio

I have a mock `DatasetWriter` object and a function to write an array into the object.

```py
def write_dataset(dataset: DatasetWriter, image: np.ndarray):
    dataset.write(image)
```

Now, I want to write a unittest for this function.

```py
def test_write_dataset():
    output_dataset = Mock(DatasetWriter)
    write_dataset(dataset=output_dataset, image=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
    print(output_dataset.read())
    assert (output_dataset.read() == np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])).all()
```

The output:

```sh
============================================================= FAILURES ==============================================================
________________________________________________________ test_write_dataset _________________________________________________________

    def test_write_dataset():
        output_dataset = Mock(DatasetWriter)
        write_dataset(dataset=output_dataset, image=np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
        print(output_dataset.read())
>       assert (output_dataset.read() == np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])).all()
E       AssertionError: assert False
E        +  where False = <built-in method all of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7f21fdba24b0>()
E        +    where <built-in method all of numpy.ndarray object at 0x7f21fdba24b0> = <Mock name='mock.read()' id='139783967501328'> == array([[1, 2, 3],\n       [4, 5, 6]]).all
E        +      where <Mock name='mock.read()' id='139783967501328'> = <Mock name='mock.read' id='139783967501088'>()
E        +        where <Mock name='mock.read' id='139783967501088'> = <Mock spec='DatasetWriter' id='139783967500752'>.read
E        +      and   array([[1, 2, 3],\n       [4, 5, 6]]) = <built-in function array>([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
E        +        where <built-in function array> = np.array

tests/liveeo/test_processing.py:134: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------
<Mock name='mock.read()' id='139783967501328'>
========================================================= 1 failed in 0.55s =========================================================
```

My question is that the mock object `output_dataset` can not perform the operation of `write` in the `write_dataset` function. How could I write a unittest for the function `write_dataset`. Thanks.

Comment: If you mock `dataset`, you cannot test it, so what you actually want to test?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I want to test `write_dataset` function. I know a trick of using `rasterio.io.MemoryFile` (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329434/creating-an-in-memory-rasterio-dataset-from-numpy-array), but I am wondering if there is another way of testing the function `write_dataset` without creating temporary `MemoryFile` but using `DatasetWriter` directly instead. What do you mean by "If you mock dataset, you cannot test it"? AFAIK, `Mock` can *fake* an object and let us test it. I may understand `Mock` wrongly.

Comment: Mock fakes an object by replacing it by a mock object, that has none of the functionality of the original object, so you cannot test the original object if replacing it by a mock.